# get the count value as per the product from table

Tags: php, mysql

get the count value from the table given below

there is a table1 values and i given output .How to i get the output
i need php mysql code for this output.

table1

sorry guys i dont know how to create table.just i created.
the table contains 3 rows

space represent as ####.

```
id #### product #### reactions
------------------------
1.    axe     ####      bad
2.    colgate ####  good
3.    axe    ####   normal
4.    axe    ####   good
5.    axe    ####   bad
6.    colgate ####  good
7.    axe     ####  bad
8.    axe     ####  normal
9.    axe      #### good
10.   colgate  #### bad
```

ouput

```
id #### product #### good #### bad #### normal ##

1.    axe   ####   2   ####  3   #### 2
2.   colgate  #### 2   ####  1   #### 0
```

Comment: if you didn't even find out how to make the tables, what did you do by yourself for solving this question?

Comment: i know how to create a table and other mysql functions...i mentions that i dont know how to design a table in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, product, SUM(reactions = 'bad') AS bad, SUM(reactions = 'good') AS good,
    SUM(reactions = 'normal') AS normal
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY product
```